# Merging scalaz-stream input processes seems to "wait" on stdin

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I have a simple program:

```
import scalaz._
import stream._

object Play extends App {
  val in1 = io.linesR("C:/tmp/as.txt")
  val in2 = io.linesR("C:/tmp/bs.txt")

  val p = (in1 merge in2) to io.stdOutLines
  p.run.run
}
```

The file `as.txt` contains five `a`s and the file `bs.txt` contain 3 `b`s. I see this sort of output:

```
a
b
b
a
a
b
a
a
a
```

However, when I change the declaration of `in2` as follows:

```
val in2 = io.stdInLines
```

Then I get what I think is unexpected behaviour. According to the documentation **[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxBEUyIBt0)**, the program should pull data non-deterministically from each stream according to whichever stream is quicker to supply stuff. This should mean that I see a bunch of `a`s immediately printed to the console but this is not what happens at all.

Indeed, until I press `ENTER`, nothing happens. It's quite clear that the behaviour looks a lot like what I would expect if I was choosing a stream at random to get the next element from and then, if that stream was blocking, the merged process blocks too (even if the other stream contains data).

What is going on?

**[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxBEUyIBt0)** - well, OK, there is very little documentation, but *Dan Spiewak* said very clearly in [his talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxBEUyIBt0) that it would grab whoever was the first to supply data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the implementation of `stdInLines`. It is blocking, it never `Task.fork`s a thread.

Try changing the implentation of `stdInLines` to this one:

```
def stdInLines: Process[Task,String] =
    Process.repeatEval(Task.apply { 
    Option(scala.Console.readLine())
    .getOrElse(throw Cause.Terminated(Cause.End))
})
```

The original `io.stdInLines` is running the `readLine()` in the same thread, so it always waits there until you type something.